# serial port reads incorrect data on windows

Tags: c, windows, winapi, serial-port

this program is to receive and then send data through serial port.

After setting up serial, read a byte from serial(i'm using a tool called putty to send chars), if it is a 'a', read 16byte from a file and then send to serial, and then reads a 'b', and goes on to lettle 'p'. total 16 loops.

but now, i can have the first two loops work, when it comes to the third loop, after readfile(), the **readBuff** is 50h, while it is what it reads from serial for the first 2 loops, like 'a', 'b'.
it always fails at the 3rd loop.

it is weird, does someone have a clue?

```
hSerial = CreateFile("COM1",                            
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,       
        0,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
        0
        );

if(hSerial==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
    if(GetLastError()==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND){
        printf("create serial handle file failed!-1");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("create serial handle file failed!-2");
    return 0;
}
DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
dcbSerialParams.fBinary = TRUE;
dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_9600;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize   = 8;
dcbSerialParams.StopBits   = ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity       = NOPARITY;
if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams)){
    printf("set serial state failed");
    return 0;
}
    COMMTIMEOUTS cmt;

cmt.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1;
cmt.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 100000000;
cmt.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 100000000;
cmt.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 10;
cmt.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 10;

if(!SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &cmt)){
    printf("set timeout failed");
    return 0;
}
char readBuff; //read 1 byte from serial which indicate the send loop
DWORD dwBytesRead; //number of bytes read from binary
char writeBuff[16]; /*read 16bytes from spd binary to write to serial */
DWORD dwBytesWrite; /*stores actual number of bytes writen*/
for(int i = 0; i<=15; i++){
    //initial the variables to 0 incase some weird behavior
    readBuff = 0; 
    dwBytesRead = 0;
    dwBytesWrite = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<=15; j++)
        writeBuff[j] = 0;

    if(!ReadFile(hSerial, &readBuff, 1 , &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
        if(dwBytesRead != 1){
            printf("read failed, please check!\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
//when it comes to the 3rd loop, readfile() reads a 50h, even if i didn't send anything to serial line.
    if(readBuff != ('a' + i)){
        printf("failed the %dth loop\n", i);
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        //read spd binary then puts to serial

        if(fread(writeBuff, 1, 16, file) != 16){
            printf("read binary failed, please check!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        //send to serial
        if(!WriteFile(hSerial, writeBuff, 16, &dwBytesWrite, NULL)){
            if(dwBytesWrite != 16){
                printf("write to serial failed, please check!\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        printf("%c", readBuff);

    }
}//end of for loop
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ReadFile fails you need to read again until you have found some valid data. But instead, you check dwBytesRead and makes the decision to continue based on what's in that variable. When ReadFile fails, I wouldn't trust dwBytesRead to contain a valid value. Suppose the UART read 1 byte but got an overrun/framing error?

Change the program to

```
   while(!ReadFile(...))
     ;
```

Comment: thank you very much @Lundin, i have tried your suggestion, which indeed solves the problem, i change the program to read continuously until it reads what is expected, for this instance, 'c' is there after 50h. although it still receive 50h, but now it can works as expected.

Comment: @svenwang You simply can't trust the contents of the input buffer before ReadFile returns true.

Comment: although it is not important to me, but the 50h still apears at the third loop. it's really strange to me, maybe i need more knowledge of how windows serial port works to figure that out.

Comment: @svenwang Hmm ok if you get garbage between the symbols there is likely some misconfiguration or hardware error. If you have access to an oscilloscope, look at the data and ensure that it has the correct speed and that there's no noise. Also ensure that the signal grounds are connected to each other.